# Blinking Cursor! Cordova/Phonegap IOS

Tags: ios, css, cordova, textinput

I am battling with the blinking cursor on a text input box.  The text input box is a sky blue and the blinking cursor is a dark blue which looks undesirable.  I have tried all the css I could find to either change the colour or remove it completely.  Has anyone got experience of this and wether this can actually be done? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you, the bad part is that you don't know were the cursor is!

```css
input[type="text"]{
    color : transparent;
    text-shadow : 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="test message" />
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Cheers. yes it worked, but as you say the cursor cannot be seen which is a shame.  Thanks though!